# How to implement execCommand of Twisted SSH server for use with fabric?

Tags: python, ssh, twisted, paramiko, fabric

I implemented a Twisted SSH server to test a component that uses fabric to run commands on a remote machine via SSH. I have found [this example](https://docs.twistedmatrix.com/en/twisted-20.3.0/_downloads/2cc3ee3e05ebfb5e87e57ff98dd9b5c6/sshsimpleserver.py) but I don't understand how I have to implement the `execCommand` method to be compatible with fabric. Here is my implementation of the SSH server:

```
from pathlib import Path

from twisted.conch import avatar, recvline
from twisted.conch.insults import insults
from twisted.conch.interfaces import ISession
from twisted.conch.ssh import factory, keys, session
from twisted.cred import checkers, portal
from twisted.internet import reactor
from zope.interface import implementer

SSH_KEYS_FOLDER = Path(__file__).parent.parent / "resources" / "ssh_keys"


@implementer(ISession)
class SSHDemoAvatar(avatar.ConchUser):
    def __init__(self, username: str):
        avatar.ConchUser.__init__(self)
        self.username = username
        self.channelLookup.update({b"session": session.SSHSession})

    def openShell(self, protocol):
        pass

    def getPty(self, terminal, windowSize, attrs):
        return None

    def execCommand(self, protocol: session.SSHSessionProcessProtocol, cmd: bytes):
        protocol.write("Some text to return")
        protocol.session.conn.sendEOF(protocol.session)

    def eofReceived(self):
        pass

    def closed(self):
        pass


@implementer(portal.IRealm)
class SSHDemoRealm(object):
    def requestAvatar(self, avatarId, _, *interfaces):
        return interfaces[0], SSHDemoAvatar(avatarId), lambda: None


def getRSAKeys():
    with open(SSH_KEYS_FOLDER / "ssh_key") as private_key_file:
        private_key = keys.Key.fromString(data=private_key_file.read())

    with open(SSH_KEYS_FOLDER / "ssh_key.pub") as public_key_file:
        public_key = keys.Key.fromString(data=public_key_file.read())

    return public_key, private_key


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sshFactory = factory.SSHFactory()
    sshFactory.portal = portal.Portal(SSHDemoRealm())

    users = {
        "admin": b"aaa",
        "guest": b"bbb",
    }
    sshFactory.portal.registerChecker(checkers.InMemoryUsernamePasswordDatabaseDontUse(**users))
    pubKey, privKey = getRSAKeys()
    sshFactory.publicKeys = {b"ssh-rsa": pubKey}
    sshFactory.privateKeys = {b"ssh-rsa": privKey}
    reactor.listenTCP(22222, sshFactory)
    reactor.run()
```

Trying to execute a command via fabric yields the following output:

```
[paramiko.transport  ][INFO    ] Connected (version 2.0, client Twisted_22.4.0)
[paramiko.transport  ][INFO    ] Authentication (password) successful!
Some text to return
```

This looks promising but the program execution hangs after this line. Do I have to close the connection from the server side after executing the command? How do I implement that properly?

Answer (score 0):

In a traditional UNIX server, it's still the server's responsibility to close the connection if it was told to execute a command. It's up to the server's discretion where and how to do this.

I *believe* you just want to change `protocol.session.conn.sendEOF(protocol.session)` to `protocol.loseConnection()`.  I apologize for not testing this myself to be sure, setting up an environment to properly test a full-size conch setup like this is a bit tedious (and the example isn't self-contained, requiring key generation and moduli, etc)